# Prevent description list items from collapsing when values are missing

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Rails 3.2 application and my "Show" view lists the fields and values for people. For this example let's assume the values are

```
name
address1
address2
city
state
zip
```

I can't be assured that all data elements will have values for each label. For example address2 will seldom be filled in. That results in the values for city, state and zip to align with the wrong labels.

Is there a way I can make things line up with their appropriate label without having to throw it into a table? I'd like to avoid that mess if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on how you are displaying the data.  Here is an approach.

```
<% if(lable_value.empty? || lable_value.nil?) %>
  <%= "<br />".html_safe %>
<% else %>
  <%= lable_value %>
<% end %>
```